# Accessing C# session varible in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I am trying to access a session variable in aspx but I think there is an issue with my syntax somewhere.

Under page load:

```
Session["UserName"]= username.Substring(8).ToString();  // This is ok as far as I know.
```

Issue is with the asp bit:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ATextBox" runat="server" Text="<% Session["UserName"] %>" /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="ATextBox" runat="server" Text="<%# Session["UserName"] %>" />
```

I have also tried the above (one at a time) with `.ToString()` at the end too. But I keep getting errors:

`Either The server tag is not well formed or the server tag contains % %`

One thing that might make a difference is the `Textbox` is inside a `GridView`, (it is inside a `ContentTemplate`)but not a boundfield.

Comment: Is there any particular error you're encountering?

Comment: @Paul `Either The server tag is not well formed or the server tag contains % %`

Comment: Can you not simply set the textbox value in the page load event?

Comment: No, I think because it is inside a Gridview I can't access it. And I don't want to resort to Findcontrol yet

Comment: `<asp:TextBox ID="ATextBox" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval( Session["UserName"] ) %>" /> ` should work, unfortunately it requires `ATextBox.DataBind()` in `Page_Load`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ATextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Session["UserName"] %>' />
```

Not sure if it would help..

Comment: Thanks mate, all sorted

Comment: What about if the session has  timeout?

Comment: I believe it will be just empty, i am not converting to any data type here, and the texbox needs a string as Text.

Comment: The session variable is refreshed (populated) on page load. And if my understanding is correct All the text boxes will get populated on page load. So is there a chance of the textboxes being empty?